# How do I get to my Google App Engine project's API explorer?

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I get to my Google App Engine project's API explorer?
Like this gentleman did in the [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=NU_wNR_UUn4#t=1245) video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access your API Explorer, you will need to start the Local Development Server.

Then via your local browser, visit the following: `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer`

Note: Please substitute the port 8888 with your specific port number, if needed.

Reference : Step #5 on the following page in the [Endpoints tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api).

Comment: I ended up accessing my project via this (fake project name for security) url: https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-project-notreal-java-eclipse.appspot.com%2F_ah%2Fapi#p/

Comment: When you type the url that i have provided, it will redirect to the one that you have mentioned. You do not need to explicitly type that url.

Comment: Can you help with this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942118/failing-to-generate-all-the-header-and-implementation-classed-for-ios