# Failing to generate all the header and implementation classed for iOS

Tags: java, ios, api, google-app-engine

I'm on step 5 of the [Using Endpoints in an iOS Client tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios) and when I try to generate all the header and implementation classes for iOS by utilizing the tictactoe-v1-rpc.discovery file it's currently failing with "ERROR: Failed to fetch the api description" (see below)

In the terminal I enter:

> ConfusedDeer-mbp:/ ConfusedDeer$
>   /Users/ConfusedDeer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceGenerator-eoemzskhioxhvgbxjfcwxowhamno/Build/Products/Debug/ServiceGenerator
>   \ ~/Desktop/tictactoe-v1-rpc.discovery --outputDir
>   /Users/ConfusedDeer/Desktop/API

===============================================================================

Generation Settings:

Output Directory:

> ~/Desktop/API

Discovery RPC URL: https://www.googleapis.com/rpc?prettyPrint=false

Flags:

- Use service name directory: NO
- Remove unknown files: NO
- Add 'Generated' directory: NO
- Allow rootURL overrides: YES

Loading API File(s):

- Fetching / ~/Desktop/tictactoe-v1-rpc.discovery

> ERROR: Failed to fetch the api description /
>   ~/Desktop/tictactoe-v1-rpc.discovery, error: Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on
>   this server." UserInfo=0x7fec72c2cf30
>   {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fec72c2c680 "The requested URL was not found on
>   this server.",
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///%20~/Desktop/tictactoe-v1-rpc.discovery,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///%20~/Desktop/tictactoe-v1-rpc.discovery,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this
>   server.}

Generating:

Writing:

- No changes from what is already on disk.

ConfusedDeer-mbp:/ ConfusedDeer$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further troubleshooting I was finally able to generate my iOS client libraries!

The command I used to accomplish this was:

> /Users/ConfusedDeer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceGenerator-eoemzskhioxhvgbxjfcwxowhamno/Build/Products/Debug/ServiceGenerator /Users/ConfusedDeer/Desktop/tictactoe-v1-rpc.discovery --outputDir /Users/ConfusedDeer/Desktop/API

There were two issues with the original command I was using. I was finally able to locate the issue by placing:

> file:///%20~/Desktop/tictactoe-v1-rpc.discovery

In the browser URL and noticed there was a %20, which is a space. Once I removed all the spaces and the tilde (~) and placed the following in the URL

> file:///Users/ConfusedDeer/Desktop/tictactoe-v1-rpc.discovery

once the rpc.discovery file appeared in the browser I realized that the google commmand line tool would be able to locate it.
Another issue was the output directory had to be relative (duh!) from where I executed the command in the terminal..

After I ran:

> /Users/ConfusedDeer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceGenerator-eoemzskhioxhvgbxjfcwxowhamno/Build/Products/Debug/ServiceGenerator /Users/ConfusedDeer/Desktop/tictactoe-v1-rpc.discovery --outputDir /Users/ConfusedDeer/Desktop/API

in generated the following:

> ===============================================================================
>   Generation Settings:
>
> Output Directory: ~/Desktop/API
>
> Discovery RPC URL: https://www.googleapis.com/rpc?prettyPrint=false
>
> Flags:
>
> - Use service name directory: NO
>
>   - Remove unknown files: NO
>   - Add 'Generated' directory: NO
>   - Allow rootURL overrides: YES
>       Loading API File(s):
>   - Fetching ~/Desktop/tictactoe-v1-rpc.discovery
>       +-- Loaded: tictactoe:v1
>       Generating:
>   - tictactoe(v1)
>       Writing:
>   - GTLQueryTictactoe.h (1744 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLQueryTictactoe.m (1907 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLServiceTictactoe.h (1507 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLServiceTictactoe.m (1472 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLTictactoe.h (583 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLTictactoe_Sources.m (702 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLTictactoeBoard.h (725 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLTictactoeBoard.m (638 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLTictactoeConstants.h (663 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLTictactoeConstants.m (529 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLTictactoeScore.h (974 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLTictactoeScore.m (879 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLTictactoeScoreCollection.h (976 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLTictactoeScoreCollection.m (918 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLTictactoeUser.h (878 bytes) - NEW
>   - GTLTictactoeUser.m (682 bytes) - NE

SUCCESS!

Comment: I am a confused deer.

    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceGenerator-btnyogexyyjtgrgbfjqddcedmkls/Build/Products/Debug/ServiceGenerator \ /Users/username/Documents/filename.discovery \ --outputDir /Users/username/API

I get...ERROR: An output directory is required.